# unknown facility name "local8"

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I'm setting up remote logging for the first time and am able to output all httpd messages to local6.  I'm getting an error, and have a general question about rsyslog.

**First:**

I tried splitting error and access into seperate facilities with this configuration:

httpd.conf:

> ErrorLog "| tee -a /var/log/httpd/error.log | logger
>   -thttpd_servername_error -plocal6.err" CustomLog "|tee -a /var/log/httpd/access.log | logger -thttpd_servername_access
>   -plocal8.notice" combined

rsyslog.conf:

```
# httpd messages
local6.*                                      /var/log/httpd_error.log
local8.*                                      /var/log/httpd_access.log
```

After restarting rsyslog I get this error:

```
Apr  7 13:36:44 boxname rsyslogd-3000: unknown facility name "local8"
```

**Second:**

It seems counter-intuitive to have log data going to three places:

- default httpd log in /var/log/httpd/error.log
- rsyslog in /var/log/httpd_error.log
- remote host (defined at bottom of rsyslog.conf)

I want local log files written and retained in addition to off-site logging, but I don't like the idea of having identical log data going in *two* local files.

Am I missing something important here?   Is it possible to skip having rsyslog (redundantly) write to a local file and *only* send data remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's only facility levels local0-local7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Facility_levels), no local8.

Comment: Yeah I figured out my mistake a few minutes ago.  I have error and access going to separate facilities.   I'm still unsure why I need to output to new files what is already being written to the existing apache logfiles (virtualhosts in play, and the apache log files are well organized).

Comment: @acoder: can you edit to include the forwarding part of your rsyslog.conf? To a zeroth approximation, I'd think simply not declaring a rule to send `local6.*` to a local file would solve your problem?

Comment: Got it - I disabled the file streams and am just sending data via port 514 to external logger.  Much better now.

Comment: Is it possible to further filter what is sent to the external server?  Could I exclude notices from local5, for instance?

Comment: @acoder: I should think so, but I'm not sitting at a machine with rsyslog (and its manpages) isntalled right now.

Comment: man page is >822 pages long - hoped it would be an easy thing to regurgitate.